# pdflatex - quiet mode

Tags: errors, compiling, warnings

I am using

> mactex

to compile my .tex file.
I want to

> suppress all error and warning messages.

I have tried this using the below commands but none of them work:

Xelatex

```
xelatex report.tex --interaction=errorstopmode; 
xelatex report.tex --interaction=batchmode
```

pdflatex

```
pdflatex report.tex --interaction=batchmode;
pdflatex report.tex -quiet -f;
pdflatex report.tex -quiet=true;
pdflatex report.tex -interaction=nonstopmode;
```

Please help me figure out what should I do to stop all errors and warnings.
My file compiles how I want it to, I don't want it to show me any messages, just compile in one line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every warning and every error message is a sign that there are (possible) problems. Worst case: Your document runs into too many errors and cannot be compiled, ten minutes before the deadline.\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This command line should produce no output at all.  It also works with `xelatex` and `lualatex`.

```
pdflatex --interaction=batchmode test.tex 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

This will perform great until you get a partial PDF or no PDF at all.  Happy debugging!